# In EModE should 'may' become 'mayest' when expressing a wish

Tags: grammar, early-modern-english

I'm translating a text from Sanskrit, which has a singular/plural (and, actually, dual) distinction in the second person. It has long been the custom in English translation to render the 2nd singular with 'thou', etc. and the 2nd plural with 'ye/you', etc., as in Early Modern English (EModE). This creates a suitably archaic and liturgical feel to the translation.

But I've come unstuck with the phrase 'may you be covered'. If I want to replace 'you' with 'thou', should 'may' become 'mayest' or not?

My feeling is that 'may' is functioning as an auxiliary here. In Modern English, we say 'he likes it', but 'may he like it'. We do not say 'mays he like it', the 'may' is not a finite verb. So I would expect the same to apply to EModE.

However, we would also apply the same logic to 'should'. We would say 'Has he eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded him that he should not eat?', not '... that he shoulds not eat?'. And so I would have expected, applying that logic, to find '... that thou should not eat?'. And yet we have in Genesis:

> And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?
>
> (Genesis 3:11)

Which leads me to question whether the may would be finite and agree with thou, or not. Should it be 'mayest thou be covered' or 'may thou be covered', and why? This, to be clear, is in the sense of an imperative: 'Be covered!' - only softer.

Comment: I'm no expert but I would say that it ought to be *mayest* and *shouldest*, if you are speaking Early Modern English.

Comment: Be covered = cover yourself?

Comment: @TimRomano Be covered doesn't seem to equal cover yourself here, going by the form of the verb and the rest of the sentence. The commentary to the text also suggests it's somebody else doing the covering, although another exegetical text does say 'cover yourself'. I think the sense really is best expressed by 'may you be covered', although I may be wrong in my translation. But I wanted to make clear that 'may', here, is in the sense of 'may you live in interesting times' and not of 'may I go?' or 'you may go'

Comment: You could say **mayest thou be ...**.

Comment: @TimRomano You *could,* but it changes the meaning because it's no longer in the subjunctive mood. "Mayest thou" would in fact never be said, because it means the same as "thou mayest"; **"may thou"** is not the same form at all.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Could you please clarify your comment? The antecedents of your pronouns **it**  and **it's** are unclear, and not clear what you mean to say with your second sentence ("it would in fact never be said") and what are the comparands in the final clause "...not the *same* form at all."?

Comment: @Tim "Mayest thou" means the same as "thou mayest" (because both are **indicative**). "May thou" is **subjunctive;** thus "mayest thou" and "may thou" are not equivalent.

Comment: @Andrew:  *Mayest thou ...* is a periphrastic form of expressing a wish; the inversion marks the verb-phrase as not a statement of fact.

Comment: @TimRomano Not in EModE, in my lengthy experience with the Book of Common Prayer and slightly more limited exposure to Shakespeare and Chaucer (as a ME precursor).

Comment: @Andrew: Shakespeare (as well as the King James bible, I assume) seems to have conjugated modal verbs in 2nd person subjunctive as *"thou mayst", "thou shouldst", "thou wouldst"*, and so forth. Shakespeare used *"mayst thou"* 16 times (most of them clearly subjunctive), and never used *"may thou"* even once. For example, *"long mayst thou live 
to bear his image and renew his glories!"*

Comment: @PeterShor regarding the KJV, I could not find "may thou", [but I had a look for "mayest thou"](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=mayest+thou&qs_version=KJV). All examples with that word order seemed to me to be indicative, but some examples of "thou mayest" seem to be subjunctive. My ability with grammatical analysis is not strong enough for me to be confident, but consider Genesis 28:3-4

Comment: "And God Almighty bless thee, and make thee fruitful, and multiply thee, **that thou mayest be** a multitude of people; And give thee the blessing of Abraham, to thee, and to thy seed with thee; **that thou mayest inherit** the land wherein thou art a stranger, which God gave unto Abraham."

Comment: @Au101: that does look like the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you would use *mayest* with *thou*. Modal verbs (*mayest, mightst, wilt, wouldst, canst, couldst, shalt, shouldst*) were conjugated only in 2nd person singular.

The question is whether you still use *mayest* if the sentence is in the subjunctive mood, or whether you use the bare infinitive *may*. With main verbs, the subjunctive mood used the bare infinitive, even in 2nd person singular. Did modal verbs obey the same rules?

The evidence from Shakespeare (one of the two standard exemplars of Early Modern English) is that they did not. Even in constructions we would expect to be in the subjunctive mood, modal verbs are still conjugated by adding an *-est*. Shakespeare used *mayst thou* 16 times, and never once used *may thou*. And the following are clearly wishes:

> O Imogen, safe mayst thou wander, safe return again!

> In dreadful war mayst thou be overcome,
> Or live in peace abandon'd and despised!

> long mayst thou live
> To bear his image and renew his glories!

> Hermia, sleep thou there:
> And never mayst thou come Lysander near!

> Of all say'd yet, mayst thou prove prosperous!
> Of all say'd yet, I wish thee happiness!

> Ill mayst thou thrive, if thou grant any grace!

> Long mayst thou live to wail thy children's loss;

> Long mayst thou live in Richard's seat to sit,
> And soon lie Richard in an earthly pit!

The last of these examples pairs *"mayst thou live"* with the subjunctive *"soon lie Richard"* (not *"lies"*), so we see that *"mayst"* was used here in parallel with the subjunctive mood for a non-modal verb.

Your quote from Genesis uses *thou shouldest* in a context that should be in the subjunctive and Tim Romano has found *mayest thou* for a wish, that would normally be in the subjunctive mood. My conclusion is that in Middle English, **for auxiliary verbs**, the conjugation was still "thou mayest", "thou shouldest" and so forth, even in the subjunctive. As more support for this conclusion, Shakespeare wrote

> How dearly would it touch me to the quick,
> Shouldst thou but hear I were licentious
> And that this body, consecrate to thee,
> By ruffian lust should be contaminate!

and clauses starting *should* always have a counterfactual meaning, something which normally triggers the subjunctive mood.

So use *mayest thou*.

One more thing—today hardly anybody understands the details of Middle English grammar, so hardly any of your readers will even notice if you use the wrong verb form.

Answer (score 3):

Even in Early Modern English, the subjunctive uses the infinitive form of the verb.

One example (which is a recent construction, but in EModE) is:

> We proclaim thy death, O Lord, and profess thy resurrection,
>   until thou **come** again.
>
> *Divine Worship Missal;* see no. 23 of [this analysis](http://www.theanglocatholic.com/tag/masses-for-the-dead/)

The example *shouldest* does not form the subjunctive mood; it's indicative.

Thus, where *may* is expressing a wish, it is indeed *May thou*.

Comment: I have no idea why in the example *shouldest* isn't in the subjunctive. It would be in modern American English. (e.g., *"Has he eaten from the tree, from which I commanded that he not eat."*)

Comment: Correction to my previous comment, *shouldst* ***is*** in the subjunctive in that example. In Early Modern English, the 2nd person subjunctive of modal verbs was *thou mayst, thou shouldst*, and so on. For example, from Shakespeare: *"In dreadful war mayst thou be overcome, Or live in peace abandon'd and despised!"* Shakespeare ***never*** used *"may thou"*.

Comment: I think this is a good answer and I think we must remember that EModE was not very standardised then, nor do I believe "EModE" is that well-defined now (as in, different people may include different things under that label). So the answer is probably both "may" and "mayest" were used, but I gave @PeterShor the green tick, because I thought he did a good job of the why

Comment: I was debating whether to suggest that EModE should actually be subdivided itself, into Early EModE and Late EModE (or maybe "Transitional" or something) because English was certainly evolving during the period. It's entirely possible that Shakespeare was at the cutting edge of language development (standardising on *Mayest*) and the Church was conservatively preserving the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

OP wants to know "In EModE should 'may' become 'mayest' when expressing a wish? ... If I want to replace 'you' with 'thou', should 'may' become 'mayest' or not?"

Yes, **may** would become **mayest** with **thou**.

> Mayest thou be ...

Consider [this example from 1628](https://books.google.com/books?id=ucGRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mayest%20thou%22&dq=%22mayest%20thou%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivz9j57sfMAhXLPD4KHTxdBioQ6AEIVzAO).

> Mayest thou perish unpittied, for making of the Virgin Graces,
>   Harlots.

*May you perish unpitied for making harlots of the Virgin Graces.*

Comment: This is interesting. I find in the 18th century several books containing an explanation of the Lord's Prayer: *Thy Kingdom come: Mayest Thou rule and reign in all the affections of our hearts, and over all the actions of our lives ; swaying Thy Sceptre of Righteousness ... *. But the original from 1673 says [May thou](https://books.google.com/books?id=WwQLrGc_DuAC&q=%22thy+kingdom+come+may+thou%22&dq=%22thy+kingdom+come+may+thou%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFx_Ts88fMAhXCoD4KHf0EByoQ6AEIHTAA).

Comment: The "original"?

Comment: I assume it's the original. The 1673 book has Richard Sherlock as the author, and the 1843 book has Richard Sherlock listed as a co-author.

Comment: Why the downvote? Despite the quibble in my comment, I think this answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Another example of *mayst* in a wish: From Shakespeare: *"In dreadful war mayst thou be overcome, Or live in peace abandon'd and despised!"*